# How to group arrays of objects by value and add the result to another array with same value at specific key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this situation:

```
const array1 = [
  {
    node:
    {
      id: '789dg020hgn20ijahq',
      family: 'ps4',
      featuredImage: 'URL'
    }
  },
  {
    node:
     {
       id: 'gf80s70ga09ggds90ds000s9',
       family: 'xbox-one',
       featuredImage: 'URL'
     }
   }
]

const array2 = [
  {
    node:
      {
      id: 'h83g01whiehq8haos',
      family: 'nintendo-switch',
      gameName: 'Mario Cart'
    }
  },
  {
    node:
      {
      id: '1290qas9a0k19po1',
      family: 'xbox-one',
      gameName: 'COD WWII'
      }
    },
    {
      node:
        {
        id: '09ga09guh3njf32olkls',
        family: 'xbox-one',
        gameName: 'GOW 2'
        }
      }
]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to group these arrays by `family` key and have this new array:

```
*output I want*
[{
  family: {
    id: 'gf80s70ga09ggds90ds000s9',
    family: 'xbox-one',
    featuredImage: 'URL',

    games: [
      0: {
        id: '1290qas9a0k19po1',
        family: 'xbox-one',
        gameName: 'COD WWII'
      },
      1: {
        id: '09ga09guh3njf32olkls',
        family: 'xbox-one',
        gameName: 'GOW 2'
      }
    ]
  },

  family: {
    id: 'h83g01whiehq8haos',
    family: 'nintendo-switch',
    featuredImage: 'URL',

    games: []
  }
]

*if the family of the array1 is not matched in array2*
family: {
   id: '789dg020hgn20ijahq',
   family: 'ps4',
   featuredImage: 'URL',

   games: []
}
```

Using this code, I grouped the arrays by `family`, but I missed some informations. How can I modify the following code to have the desired result? Sorry but I am a little bit stuck....

```
const testing2 = result[1].map((obj) => { // result[1] comes from a Promise
    return obj.node
})
_.mapValues(_.groupBy(testing2, 'family'), (list) => list.map((o) => _.omit(o, 'family')))
```

Comment: This question doesn't make a lot of sense. You say you want things grouped by family but they seemed to be grouped by manufacturer. You have a Switch manufacturer but you don't include the game in it. I suggest adding the exact output you want.

Comment: Sorry, wrong transcription. Replaced `manufacturer` with `family`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and group by `family`.

```js
var array1 = [{ node: { id: '789dg020hgn20ijahq', family: 'nintendo-switch', featuredImage: 'URL' } }, { node: { id: 'gf80s70ga09ggds90ds000s9', family: 'xbox-one', featuredImage: 'URL' } }],
    array2 = [{ node: { id: 'h83g01whiehq8haos', family: 'nintendo-switch', gameName: 'Mario Cart' } }, { node: { id: '1290qas9a0k19po1', family: 'xbox-one', gameName: 'COD WWII' } }, { node: { id: '09ga09guh3njf32olkls', family: 'xbox-one', gameName: 'GOW 2' } }, { node: { id: '09ga09guh3njf32olkls', family: 'foo', gameName: 'GOW 2' } }],
    map = new Map,
    result = array1.map(function (o) {
        map.set(o.node.family, []);
        return { family: Object.assign({}, o.node, { games: map.get(o.node.family) }) };
    });

array2.forEach(o => {
    if (!map.has(o.node.family)) {
        map.set(o.node.family, []);
        result.push({ family: { family: o.node.family, games: map.get(o.node.family) } });
    }
    map.get(o.node.family).push(o.node);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Sorry @Nina but if the family name is not found in the second one, at the moment you code fail...

Comment: what should happen in this case?

Comment: sorry, I updated the question. If the family of the `array1` is not found in the `array2`,  just create the family object with `games: []` as you can see in the question. The `array1` is the master. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `reduce` + `filter`.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/manivecoma/edit?js,console)

```
const outputArr = array1.reduce((acc, nxt) => {
  const {id, family, featuredImage} = nxt.node;
  const newObj = {id, family, featuredImage, games: []};
  const array2Match = array2.filter(obj => obj.node.family === family);

  if(!!array2Match.length) {
    newObj.games.push(array2Match[0]);
  }
  acc.push(newObj)
  return acc;
}, []);


console.log(outputArr);
```